# sandbox Activation / login is just hanging and not connecting

Tags: sandbox, login-errors

I have quite strange behavior . I could not connect to any dev or sandboxes . Login form just freez when i try to get activation code or login even to new devbox . I have try different devices and reset dns and network cache, reboot router. I see just pending post request for 2-4 minutes .

Comment: Most likely your upstream network then. Head to Starbucks...

Answer (score 2):

This is usually a connection or computer/device problem.

Try the following:

- Try getting to other websites to make sure that it's isolated to just salesforce.com. If you're having general intermittent problems, it's either your connection or your device.
- Try pinging the salesforce.com servers. See the online help for your operating system on how to ping.
- Try clearing your cache. Most browsers now support Ctrl-Shift-Del as a keyboard shortcut to clear your cache. Follow the online help for your browser of choice. This can often resolve problems.
- Try the recommended browser settings in Help & Training (Google "salesforce.com recommended browsers").
- Rarely, there's a problem with your "instance". Check [Salesforce Trust](http://trust.salesforce.com/) to see if you're affected.

Comment: Pinging should reveal it, but just in case, if you are using Windows make sure there aren't any odd entries in your hosts file that might be redirecting traffic to the wrong IP.

Comment: I noticed that it reproduced only with my router . so if i use mobile 3G internet it is work perfect . but my router dosnt have any caches . It quite simple one.